# How to get list items from another site (on the same site collection)?

Tags: 2010, site-collection, site-column

I want to get value of a column located in a list within another site but inside the same site collection. How do I do that?

Site 1: http://sitecollection/site1

Site 2: http://sitecollection/site2/subsite2/subsubsite2

Here is the way I do to get a list from the current site (site1):

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(SPContext.Current.Web.ID))
    {
        SPList currentWebList = web.GetListByInternalName(listInternalName);
    // doing stuff with list items here
    }
}
```

How to get the list from the site2 being on site1 ?

The method `getListByInternalName` is a custom method of course but it doesn't matter.

I try to replace the `Current.Site.ID` by `Current.Site.EverythingElseToGetTheRightUrlOrID` but it take way too much time to get the value so I think I'm missing something.

Does the fact that the list is located in another site could slow down processing time? (I'm just reading a column)

Answer (score 1):

You can connect directly to the web like this

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
{
    SPList currentWebList = web.GetListByInternalName(listInternalName);
    // doing stuff with list items here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the subsite by using the REST api.  A REST call similar to this (see below) should return a specific item from the subsite list.

```
http://sitecollection/site2/subsite2/subsubsite2/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Test')/items(itemid)
```

For more information on working with the SharePoint REST api you can read here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292552.aspx

---

If you want to get a list item using CSOM then its possible you could use something like this:

```
// Starting with ClientContext, the constructor requires a URL to the 
// server running SharePoint. 
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://sitecollection/site2/subsite2/subsubsite2"); 

// Assume the web has a list named "Announcements". 
List announcementsList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Announcements"); 

// This creates a CamlQuery that has a RowLimit of 100, and also specifies Scope="RecursiveAll" 
// so that it grabs all list items, regardless of the folder they are in. 
CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(100); 
ListItemCollection items = announcementsList.GetItems(query); 

// Retrieve all items in the ListItemCollection from List.GetItems(Query). 
context.Load(items); 
context.ExecuteQuery(); 
foreach (ListItem listItem in items) 
{ 
    // We have all the list item data. For example, Title. 
    label1.Text = label1.Text + ", " + listItem["Title"]; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you Tekk_Know. Is there a way to do it only by using code behind ?

Comment: @ameliapond I'm not as familiar using the CSOM, but I'll edit my answer with a possible working CSOM answer

Answer (score 0):

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url)) // get the site collection url.
{   
    // The site, subsite, subsubsite must exist under the site collection.         
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("/site2/subsite2/subsubsite2"))
    {
        // The full url of the list site including the site collection url.
        string listUrl = SPContext.Current.Site.Url + 
        "/site2/subsite2/subsubsite2/Lists/listInternalName";
        SPList list = web.GetList(listUrl);
    }
}
```